# how do I add the current logged in username in table that consist of various columns?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is my models.py file

```
From django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Campaign(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    number = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
```

This is my index.html file as  have to render models data to this below table adding current user to it and also wanted that only current logged-in user can see the current user details. Its getting difficult for me to do this because I am new to this technology.

```
% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2> Campaign List </h2>
<table class = "table">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>USERNAME</th>
            <th>CAMPAIGN NAME</th>
            <th>TEXT</th>
            <th>NUMBER</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        {% for data in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{data.username}}</td>
            <td>{{data.campaign_name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.text}}</td>
            <td>{{data.number}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

below is the error I am getting

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: campaign_campaign.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "S:\bulk_sms\campaign\views.py", line 37, in index
    print(data)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1097, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "S:\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: campaign_campaign.user_id
```

help me to solve this as I am new to django and also wanted a view of this code.

Comment: did you migrate your models properly ?

Comment: Yes I did like 2-3 times but it always shows no migrations to apply.

Comment: The error is coming from your views file, so please show that

Comment: i dont have have accurate view file bt still i will share it

Answer (score 0):

In case it show "no migrations to apply" you should add all of your app's name there

```
python manage.py makemigrations campaign
```

then it will work

Comment: i did the same bt nothing changes

Comment: You should post your views.py file here also, it seem the issue comes from your view, before you `print(data)` on line 37